# Display More then 10000 records in JqGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

IN my Database table i have more then 30,000 records,here i am trying to Display these records in **JqGrid**,Here i displayed upto 900 records only, How can i display all records in JqGrid,here i am attaching my code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetDataFromDB',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                overflow:'visible',

                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },

                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                loadonce: true,
                colNames: ['AOfficeKey', 'AChartNumber', 'APatientName', 'AVisit#'],
                colModel: [
                                { name: 'AOfficeKey', index: 'AOfficeKey', width: 80 },
                                { name: 'AChartNumber', index: 'AChartNumber', width: 150 },
                                { name: 'APatientName', index: 'APatientName', width: 160 },
                                { name: 'AVisit#', index: 'AVisit#', width: 160 }



                ],
                pager: '#pagingGrid',

                rowNum: 100,
                height: 300,
                width:600,
                rowList: [10, 100, 1000, 10000],
                gridview: true,

                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                jsonReader: {
                    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
                    root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "0"
                },

            });
        });    

    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
    <table style="border: solid 1px ; width: 100%; vertical-align: central;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt; color: chocolate;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: central; padding: 100px;">
                <table id="dataGrid" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"></table>
                <div id="pagingGrid"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

C# code is

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetDataFromDB()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Abc;Database=Training;User Id=sa;Password=abc;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * AOfficeKey,AChartNumber, APatientName,AVisit# from adjs", con))
                //("SELECT ID,Client,Location,Address FROM AClients ", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return rows;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and it works without error. However in order to load large data from server you will need to increase allowed JSON size when using json serialization. In order to do it past following code to your web.config in the <configuration> tag:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```